# Regarding Asymptotic Behaviour of normal distibution

Tags: probability-distributions

If $x_n -> \infty$ in such a way that $x_n^3/ \sqrt{n} -> 0$, then
      P{$S_n^*$ > $x_n$} ~ 1 - F($x_n$)

where $S_n^*$ is the standard normal variable and F is the normal distribution function.

(Note: This is a theorem and it has been discussed in Feller (An Introduction to Probability theory  and its applications Chap. VII sec 6). I didn't get the proof which was given there)

Comment: what is your definition of $F$?

Comment: F is the normal distribution function

Comment: isn't this a direct consequence of the definition of the distribution function?

Comment: I also thought the same. But the proof in Feller is more involved. I also don't understand the need for $x_n^3$/$\sqrt{n}$ -> 0

Comment: are you sure of your definition of $S_n^*$? it sounds more like a Cesaro mean according to the notation.

Comment: I am fairly confident.